# Wordpressで作成したフォームで、管理画面のプレビューでは正しく挙動するものの、通常のURLでは正しく挙動しない

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-apps-script

wordpressで作成した問合せフォームで、管理画面のプレビューからは理想通りの反応をするのですが、通常どおり入って操作すると理想の反応がしないのですが、どこに問題があるでしょうか。

■問題
webフォームのデータ送信が、設定したGoogleフォームに送信されていない。
※管理画面のプレビューからの操作ではデータ送信されているものの、通常で入って操作するとデータ送信されない

■補足
・初めてURLをふんだ人にも起きる現象（キャッシュ問題ではない）
・データ送信されなくても、ページ遷移はするので、データ送信に問題
・管理画面で、保存公開はしている。

---

[追記]

ご指摘ありがとうございます。以下のようなコードを記載したのですが、わかりますでしょうか。

```html
<div id="formWrapper">
    <form action="グーグルフォームのリンク"
    method="post" name="myForm" target="dummyIframe">

        <input type="submit" id="submit_button01" value="xxxx" onclick="sendGform()">
    </form>
    <iframe name="dummyIframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>
</div>

<script>
    function sendGform(){
        document.myForm.submit();
        document.getElementById('formWrapper').style.display = 'none';
        window.location.href = 'http://xxxxxxx';
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: 具体的なコードはおろかどのように実装していたのかもわからないと原因を探るのも困難かと思われます。javascriptタグをつけて投稿されていましたがWPサイト上に設置されたJSで直接GoogleフォームにJSでPOSTしている感じでしょうか。

Comment: iframeを消してlocation.hrefでリダイレクトしていますが、デバック目的でそれらを一旦コメントアウトして、iframe側で何が起きているのか確認はできないですか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。
一旦、script以下を削除してデバックした結果、iframe側に正しくデータ送信されている表示が出ており、結果データ送信もできていました。
となると、問題は、scriptが影響を与えてそうなのですが、、、

Comment: さらにデバックした結果、window.location.href = 'http://xxxxxxx';の、ページ遷移のコードを消すと、データ送信がされないことが発覚しました。。。